# Is Java cache broken? FailedDownloadException (Unable to load resource) of old jars

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, java-web-start, jnlp

The statement that the Java cache is broking might be a bit harsh, but it's the only thing I can think of at the moment. Let me sketch the situation.

I have a JavaFX application developped in Netbeans 8 which is being launched through Java webstart (JNLP). Now I have updated the applications libraries. Let me show the JNLP files:

**Previous version:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="MyApp.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <vendor>Steven</vendor>
    <description>...</description>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="Client.jar" size="1116009" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/asm-all-repackaged-2.2.0-b21.jar" size="335827" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/cglib-2.2.0-b21.jar" size="305575" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/commons-codec-1.7-javadoc.jar" size="420581" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/commons-codec-1.7-sources.jar" size="293412" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/commons-codec-1.7.jar" size="283216" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/commons-io-2.4-javadoc.jar" size="751883" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/commons-io-2.4-sources.jar" size="261467" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/commons-io-2.4.jar" size="200339" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/eclipselink.jar" size="8886159" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/guava-14.0.1.jar" size="2315551" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/hk2-api-2.2.0-b21.jar" size="144295" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/hk2-locator-2.2.0-b21.jar" size="156674" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/hk2-utils-2.2.0-b21.jar" size="74396" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar" size="31700" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/javax.inject-2.2.0-b21.jar" size="10062" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar" size="96886" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar" size="126026" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar" size="113870" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jersey-bundle-1.18.jar" size="1638880" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jersey-client.jar" size="170251" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jersey-common.jar" size="737307" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jersey-container-servlet-core.jar" size="60172" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jersey-container-servlet.jar" size="19624" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jersey-entity-filtering-2.5.1.jar" size="71150" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jersey-media-moxy-2.5.1.jar" size="29085" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jersey-server.jar" size="882351" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jfxtras-labs-0.1.jar" size="914928" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/joda-time-2.1-javadoc.jar" size="1347677" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/joda-time-2.1-sources.jar" size="721507" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/joda-time-2.1.jar" size="643526" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jxl.jar" size="783553" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/org.osgi.core-4.2.0.jar" size="261147" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar" size="24816" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/persistence-api-1.0.jar" size="64451" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar" size="78045" download="eager" />
  </resources>
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
  <applet-desc  width="1024" height="768" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="MyApp" >
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="2.2+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="1024" height="768" main-class="GUI.CL_MIT"  name="MyApp" />
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

In the new version, we switched from Java 7 to Java 8 and from Jersey 1.18 to 2. We also did a clean up from the jars as some shouldn't be in the JNLP files (javadocs, sources). So this is the JNLP file of the new version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="MyApp.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <vendor>Steven</vendor>
    <description>...</description>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="Client.jar" size="1133482" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/asm-all-repackaged-2.2.0-b21.jar" size="335848" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/cglib-2.2.0-b21.jar" size="305538" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/commons-codec-1.7.jar" size="283227" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/commons-io-2.4.jar" size="200335" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/eclipselink.jar" size="8886707" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/guava-14.0.1.jar" size="2315513" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/hk2-api-2.2.0-b21.jar" size="144294" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/hk2-locator-2.2.0-b21.jar" size="156658" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/hk2-utils-2.2.0-b21.jar" size="74374" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar" size="31704" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/javax.inject-2.2.0-b21.jar" size="10060" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar" size="96844" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar" size="126028" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar" size="113857" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jersey-client.jar" size="170237" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jersey-common.jar" size="737257" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jersey-container-servlet-core.jar" size="60162" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jersey-container-servlet.jar" size="19614" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jersey-entity-filtering-2.5.1.jar" size="71179" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jersey-media-moxy-2.5.1.jar" size="29089" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jersey-server.jar" size="882473" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/joda-time-2.1.jar" size="643623" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/jxl.jar" size="783441" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/org.osgi.core-4.2.0.jar" size="261136" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar" size="24823" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/persistence-api-1.0.jar" size="64465" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar" size="78031" download="eager" />
  </resources>
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
  <applet-desc  width="1024" height="768" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="MyApp" >
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="2.2+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="1024" height="768" main-class="GUI.CL_MIT"  name="MyApp" />
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

Now, when we launch the **new version** through our website, we get following error:

[image: Error message when launching new version]

As you may see, we get an error message saying that jar *commons-codec-1.7-javadoc.jar* is missing. How can this be? This jar is even not in the JNLP file of the new version? Why does Java try to load this jar?

So my guess was that it has something to do with the caching. I've tried following options:

- Clearing the Java cache by running *javaws -clearcache* (did not work)
- Clearing the Java cache manually by deleting the folders in *C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache* (did not work)
- Clearing the browser history and temporary files just in case (did not work)

While my hair was turning more grey by the minute, I just thought "*F--- this, I'll just disable the cache*". So I did:

- I've opened the Java control panel
- Pressed the Settings... button
- Unchecked the *Keep temporary files on my computer* option.

I went back to my website to rerun the application, saw the loading screen and I was surprised that the program ran fine... no errors whatsoever! As a matter of test, I've enabled the *Keep temporary files on my computer* option again and poof... the errors were back.

So the big question is, what on earth is going on? Am I doing something terribly wrong? Is there a problem with Netbeans compiling or am I doing something wrong with adding the libraries? Is there a problem with Java caching?

Any help, thoughts, clues would be greately appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Perneel the Grey.

Comment: I also experienced that modifying jar tags of my jnlp often results in broken webstart application, but in my case clearing the cache always worked. Not sure what caused your problem but it's true that webstart cache has lots of problems.

Comment: I hope someone has a solution for this. Did you also use Netbeans to create your application?

Comment: no I used eclipse but I don't think the choice of IDE makes any difference.

Comment: in that case we can rule out the compiling processes... the search continues

Comment: can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have created a new project and copied the src files to it and fixed the libraries. That gave the same issue. Always the same project files thou. I'll try with a blank project tomorrow